# How to setup a toggle button that triggers a periodical service?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, togglebutton

I need to implement the following function in my Android application: a toggle button that triggers off a periodical service.

Let me present the problem in a better way: I want a toggle button that has an "on" mode. In this mode I want to start a Service periodically (every 5 minutes for example). In the "off" mode the periodical Service is disabled.
I suppose I need to use an AlarmManager service.

Can you provide me the guidelines (with code if it's possible) or a  good tutorial to do this?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

Use this created methods to on and off the service on click of toggle button.
Also make sure to use AlarmManager as singleton.

```
private void setService() {

                try {
                    if (alarmManager != null) {
                        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadCastReceiver.class);

                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); //
                        // 60 seconds i.e 1 min 
                long time = 60 * 1000;

                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time, time, pendingIntent);

            }
```

To remove the serviceUpdates use the below method:

```
 private void removeService() {
            try {
                if (alarmManager != null) {
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Now the Broadcast class is supposed to be as shown below:

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Log.d("test_log", "broadcast worked ");

    }
}
```

Now comes the manifest declaration of your receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadCastReceiver"></receiver>
```

Comment: please read and study more about services and broadcast receiver from android developer guide. also please refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: thank you but i haven't understood 2 things: 1) where i have to start my IntentService? in onReceive method of MyBroadCastReceiver class? 2) can you explain me what intent and pendingintent do in the code you posted?! Thank you!

Comment: on click ontoggle button you need to call the function startservice , do whatever you need to do in OnReceive . The onReceive of the service  will automatically be called again and again in the given time interval 1 min.  Also pending intent are a time delayed intent,, to start any service or any activity